# Finding a $5\times5$ Matrix such that the sum of it and its inverse is a $5\times 5$ matrix with each entry $1$.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

How can I do this question:

Is it possible to find a $5 \times5$ invertible matrix $B$ over $\mathbb Z_2$ such that:

$B+B^{-1}=5\times5$ matrix where every element is $1$

anyway, I assume that the question requires a proof if such a matrix $B$ does not exist and working/solution(maybe?) if $B$ exists

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you left and/or right multiply by B? What properties must B have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. Denote the all-one matrix by $E$. If $B+B^{-1}=E$, then $BE=B^2+I=EB$. Therefore $B^2+I$ has identical columns and identical rows. Hence either $B^2+I=0$ or $B^2+I=E$.

1. In the first case, what is $BE$? Why is this case impossible?
2. In the second case, what are $BE,\ B^{-1}E$ and $E(B+B^{-1})E$? How do they violate the condition that $B+B^{-1}=E$?

Comment: Thanks, how did you get $B^{2}+I=0$ or $B^{2}+I=E$? couldn't it equal scalar multiples of $E$? Also, I got $BE=0$ for the first case but I'm not sure why this is impossible.  For the second, case I got $E(B+B^{-1})E=2E^{2}$ and $B+B^{-1}=E$,$ 2B=E$ then $E(B+B^{-1})E=E^{3} $which is different to the previous value of $2E^{2}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @user6156388 $\mathbb Z_2$ has only two elements: 0 and 1. As there are only two scalars, there are only two other scalar multiple of $E$. As to why $BE=0$ is impossible, please think more about it. It's really not difficult. For the second case, yes, you are correct, but please make sure that you really know why $E^3\ne2E_2$. (Again, note that there are only two scalars in $\mathbb Z_2$.)

Comment: sorry, I still don't know why $BE=0$ is impossible; can you please explain? $E^3$ cannot be $2E^2$ because the scalar 2 does not exist?

Comment: @user6156388 (1) Hint: $B$ is invertible. (2) $\mathbb Z_2$ has only two scalars: 0 and 1. What we call "2" is actually 1+1. Yet 1+1 must belong to $\mathbb Z_2$. Now, what is 1+1?

Comment: (1)ah, then $E=B^{-1}0=0$ but$ E$ is a matrix of ones. (2)1+1=0 and $E^{3} $is not equal to $0$?

Comment: @user6156388 Yes. What you say about (1) and (2) are correct.

Answer (score 2):

As user1551 did, let $E$ be the Attila matrix. When $n$ is odd, the equation $B+B^{-1}=E$ has no solutions. Yet, when $n$ is EVEN, there are.

Indeed, $E^2=0_n$, $rank(E)=1$ and $E$ is similar to $diag(J_2,0_{n-2})$ where $J_2$ is the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $2$. If $\lambda\in spectrum(B)$, then $\lambda+1/\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=1$ is the sole solution in $K$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$. Thus $B=I_n+N$ where $N$ is nilpotent and $E=(I+N)+(I-N+N^2-\cdots)=N^2-N^3+\cdots$; from $rank(E)=1=rank(N^2)$, we deduce that $N^3=0$ and $E=N^2$. Thus $B^2+I=BE=EB=E$; that is, when we assume that $B\in M_n(K)$, we obtain the same equations as when $B\in M_n(\mathbb{F}_2)$; of course, there are much more solutions over $K$.

For instance, for $n=4$, there are $12$ solutions over $\mathbb{F}_2$, including this one: $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0\\1&1&0&1\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

EDIT. About the equation $E=N^2$, the unknown $N$ must be similar to $diag(J_3,U_1,\cdots,U_p,0_{n-2p-3})$ where $U_i=J_2$.